# Evaluating product of exponent and polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a probability theory problem, I need to solve an inequality over $n\in\mathbb{N}$ which can be expressed in a general form like this:

$a^n ( b_1 n^2 + b_2 n + b_3) \leq c$ where $a, b_1, b_2, b_3, c$ are real numbers.

What is the standart way (or a good way) to tackle this? Is there an analytic solution?

For reference, here is the exact inequality:

$0.8^n ( \frac{1}{32} n^2 - \frac{7}{32} n + 1) \leq 0.1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in general to solve such equations (inequalities).

Since you have $a < 1$ there will be some $N$ such that all $n>N$ will satisfy your bound. One way to find $N$ is to guess powers of two until the statement is true. Then binary search until you find exactly $N$

viz:

$n=1 \rightarrow $ False

$n=2 \rightarrow $ False

$n=4 \rightarrow $ False

$n=8 \rightarrow $ False

$n=16 \rightarrow $ False

$n=32 \rightarrow $ True

So $N \le 32$.

Then you'd binary search between 32 and 16 until you find that $N = 21$, for all $n\ge21 = N$ the inequality is satisfied.

If you had instead that $|a|>1$, then you'd need to find some negative value of $n$ to satisfy the inequality. If instead, $a = 1$, then you could actually solve it as a quadratic equation and find an analytic solution.

Comment: This is the way suggested by my prof, but it seemed very inefficient..

Comment: It is actually not ineffiecient. In the solution's size ($N$), it is computationally effiecient. It is, in fact, $\mathcal{O}(\log N)$. In practice you do about $\log N$ steps to find the first value of TRUE, then you do about $\log \log N$ steps to terminate.

Comment: The binary search is efficient, yes, but a "straighforward" evaluation is more efficient. For example, you can often get nice evaluations from (Taylor) series expansions, but I haven't been able to use anything of that sort here.

Comment: I doubt you will be able to use an expansion. This type of thing (solutions of equations or inequalities over integers) is known to be hard. Guess and check is all we know how to do in the general case. You are lucky that you have that dominating term: $a^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's clean up a bit
$$ 0.8^n\left(\frac{1}{32}n^2-\frac{7}{32}n+1\right)\leq 0.1 $$
$$ \left(\frac{8}{10}\right)^n\left(\frac{1}{32}n^2-\frac{7}{32}n+1\right)\leq \frac{1}{10} $$
$$ \frac{8^n}{10^n}\left(\frac{1}{32}n^2-\frac{7}{32}n+1\right)\leq \frac{1}{10} $$
$$ \frac{8^n}{8}\left(\frac{1}{4}n^2-\frac{7}{4}n+8\right)\leq \frac{10^n}{10} $$
$$ 8^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{4}n^2-\frac{7}{4}n+8\right)\leq 10^{n-1} $$
$$ \frac{1}{4}n^2-\frac{7}{4}n+8\leq \frac{10^{n-1}}{8^{n-1}} $$
$$ \frac{1}{4}\left(n^2-7n+32\right)\leq \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^{n-1} $$
$$ n^2-7n+32\leq 4\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^{n-1} $$
Now let's find the minimum of the quadratic function 
$$ \frac{d}{dn}\left[ n^2-7n+32\right]=2n-7=0 $$
$$ n=\frac{7}{2}=3.5 $$
However since $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then you can start with $n=4$ and work your way up from there. I would choose $n$ in increments of $10$ as it usually doesn't take long before an exponentially increasing function becomes greater than a quadratic function. After a few more than $3$ computations, you'll realize that $n\geq 21$ renders the inequality true.

Comment: Thanks for revising "graphical comparison" with a more detailed train of thought. I like your idea of using analysis for evaluation, but sadly in this case it reduces to guessing values anyway.